# iOS8で横画面回転時に、デバイスの回転にともなってViewが回転せず、固定されてしまう

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, ios8

Xcode6,Objective-cで縦画面と横画面をボタンで切り替えられるアプリを作っています。
（縦画面と横画面ではデザインも機能も異なります。）
縦画面時はホームボタン下（Portrait)で固定し、
横画面時は回転に伴い、ホームボタン右（LandScapeRight)と
ホームボタン左（LandScapeLeft)の回転を許可したいです。

デバイスの回転はshouldAutorotateで管理しています。

```
@implementation UINavigationController (rotateControl)

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.visibleViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

縦画面時はPortraitで固定しています。

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

横画面時はLandscapeで固定しています。

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

横画面時はステータスバー（デバイス）の向きに伴い
横画面の上下回転をさせたいので
アプリケーションの環境設定のDevice Orientationに
"Landscape Left"と"Landscape Right"にチェックをつけています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、iPhone6Plus(iOS8)の実機で動かすと
横画面時に、180度回転させると、
ステータスバーの位置は常に上にくるように移動するのですが、
それに伴いUIViewが回転せず、固定されたままになってしまいます。
（iOS7のiPhone5実機、iPhone6およびiPhone6Plusのシミュレータでは期待動作です。）

ステータスバー（デバイス）の回転に伴い
横画面の上下回転をさせるにはどうしたらよろしいでしょうか・・・
ここ何日も詰まっていて困っています・・・
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問文を書き換えました・・！

Comment: 同じ内容で新たに質問を登録すると重複になってしまうので、こちらの質問を編集した方が良かったかなと思います（もしかしたら閉じられるかもしれません）。

Answer (score 1):

プログラムで操作する以前に、アプリケーションの環境設定で、180度回転を有効にしましょう。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「Device Orientation」が、デフォルトでは**Upside Down**が無効になっているので、チェックを入れて、有効にしましょう。

Comment: Harowoさんご回答ありがとうございます。

縦画面、横画面が切替可能なアプリをつくっていまして、
（縦画面時、横画面時で機能およびデザインが異なります）
縦画面時はPortraitのみ（ホームボタンが下で固定）にし、
横画面時はLandscape Left、Landscape Rightを効かせ、
横画面時の画面の上下回転を許可させたいのですが、
ここで、Viewのみ回転しません。
もし何か分かるようでしたらご回答よろしくお願いいたします。。。！
（なお、アプリケーションの環境設定は添付いただいた画像通りになっています！）

Comment: 質問文の内容と、同じことを言っていると思えません。質問文のほうを書きかえてはいかがですか？私の回答を削除することは、かまいませんので。

Comment: たしかに内容が異なっていますよね・・・質問文を書き変えます！Harawoさんご指摘ありがとうございました・・！

Answer (score 1):

どうやらiOS8のiPhone6PlusおよびiPad特有の事象のようです。

デバイスの回転はNSNotificationCenterクラスで検知し、
デバイス回転時にViewにアフィン変換の回転アニメーションをつけることで
デバイスの回転に伴いViewも回転させるようにしました。

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f // アニメーション速度
                      delay:0.0f // 何秒後にアニメーションするか
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                       // ビューを180度回転
                       float angle = 180.0 * M_PI / 180;
                       CGAffineTransform t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, angle);

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // アニメーション終了時
                     NSLog(@"アニメーション終了");
                 }];
```